# How to change styles of a pre-made Shadow DOM web component

Tags: html, jquery, css, shadow-dom

I'm using a pre-made web component name `rssapp-feed` in my HTML. This generates Instagram feed that works like an RSS, and needless to say, it comes with its own style inside a `#shadow-root`. I wanted to ask whether there is any way to change, add or overwrite the styling of the pre-made shadow DOM.

Here is the web component that I'm using in my HTML.

```
<rssapp-feed id="i0QRdHCkHgYPGNWs"></rssapp-feed><script src="https://widget.rss.app/v1/feed.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

It looks like this in the DOM.

[image]

Like if I want to add `display: flex;` to `.rssapp-feed-content` how would I do it.

Just an example would be good enough. I've seen examples online but they were mostly about creating a shadow DOM and adding styles to it.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Here is the example on [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-morning-5xl11c?file=/index.html)

Comment: Can you  make it an executable SO snippet with the [<>]  button in the editor. If I paste your code, it does nothing

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Appreciate it for looking into it mate. I tried to make executable but I was getting error for some reason so I made a demo on codesandox https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-morning-5xl11c?file=/index.html

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman if codesandbox is not convenient you can paste that web component into any code editor and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, your code needs jQuery. I unlearned that when it was no longer required, in IE9. That was 2011. Basically the answer comes down to extend the existing customElement definition, and add your own ``connectedCallback`` to inject styles.